# Sum of cubes of three different numbers is equal to the sum of cubes of three other different numbers

Tags: number-theory

I have question when I learned about Ramanujan number I thought are there any number such that cubes of three different numbers is equal to sum of cubes of three different numbers I found an answer for it myself 
$40^3+30^3+27^3=48^3+4^3+3^3$.

Here my question is it the solution or are there any solutions for it?

Comment: should it be $$a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3+e^3+f^3$$ for some integers $$a,b,c,d,e,f$$?

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046691__2

Comment: $29=3^3+1^3+1^3=4^3+(-3)^3+(-2)^3$

Comment: If you want all positive values, then $251=5^3+5^3+1^3=6^3+3^3+2^3$.

Comment: Lulu I think 5 is repeated so I think you should give another answer but your answer is excellent.how did you find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowest four such sums are:

$\begin{align*}
1009=10^3+2^3+1^3&=9^3+6^3+4^3\\
1366=11^3+3^3+2^3&=9^3+8^3+5^3\\
1457=11^3+5^3+1^3&=9^3+8^3+6^3\\
1520=11^3+5^3+4^3&=10^3+8^3+2^3
\end{align*}$

These sums and further examples (though not their decomposition into three distinct positive cubes) are at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A024974). Note, however, that that OEIS sequence includes numbers that are the sum of three distinct positive cubes in different ways where the same cube appears as a term in two ways for the same sum, e.g.
$$x^3+1729=x^3+12^3+1^3=x^3+10^3+9^3$$